# How to get resultCode and requestCode in UPI payment gateway using Android Studio and Java?

Tags: java, android-studio, payment-gateway, upi

My issue is to get the proper response for the UPI payment gateway like "Payment Success" or "Error". I tried a little bit, but this returns 0 as "resultCode" and "1" as "requestCode". But I need "resultCode" as -1. While using this code payment gets successful and also amount gets transferred but the response only not coming exactly. Kindly help me to clear this issue...

```
final int UPI_PAYMENT = 0;

payUsingUpi("TESTNAME", "testname@123","testing", "1");

public void payUsingUpi(  String name,String upiId, String note, String amount) {
        Log.e("main ", "name "+name +"--up--"+upiId+"--"+ note+"--"+amount);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay").buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter("pa", upiId)
                .appendQueryParameter("pn", name)
                .appendQueryParameter("tn", note)
                .appendQueryParameter("am", amount)
                .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
                .build();
        Intent upiPayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        upiPayIntent.setData(uri);
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");
        if(null != chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())) {
            startActivityForResult(chooser, UPI_PAYMENT);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(FinalFormActivity.this,"No UPI app found, please install one to continue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("main ", "response resultCode :  "+resultCode );
        Log.e("main ", "response requestCode :  "+requestCode );
        Log.e("main ", "data : "+data );
        switch (requestCode) {
            case UPI_PAYMENT:
                if ((RESULT_OK == resultCode) || (resultCode == 11)) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        String trxt = data.getStringExtra("response");
                        Log.e("UPI", "onActivityResult: " + trxt);
                        ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                        dataList.add(trxt);
                        upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("UPI", "onActivityResult: " + "Return data is null");
                        ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                        dataList.add("nothing");
                        upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("UPI", "onActivityResult: " + "Return data is null with back button");
                    ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                    dataList.add("nothing");
                    upiPaymentDataOperation(dataList);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

private void upiPaymentDataOperation(ArrayList<String> data) {
        if (isConnectionAvailable(FinalFormActivity.this)) {
            String str = data.get(0);
            Log.e("UPIPAY", "upiPaymentDataOperation: "+str);
            String paymentCancel = "";
            if(str == null) str = "discard";
            String status = "";
            String approvalRefNo = "";
            String response[] = str.split("&");
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                String equalStr[] = response[i].split("=");
                if(equalStr.length >= 2) {
                    if (equalStr[0].toLowerCase().equals("Status".toLowerCase())) {
                        status = equalStr[1].toLowerCase();
                    }
                    else if (equalStr[0].toLowerCase().equals("ApprovalRefNo".toLowerCase()) || equalStr[0].toLowerCase().equals("txnRef".toLowerCase())) {
                        approvalRefNo = equalStr[1];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    paymentCancel = "Payment cancelled by user.";
                }
            }
            if (status.equals("success")) {
                Toast.makeText(FinalFormActivity.this, "Transaction successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("UPI", "payment successfull: "+approvalRefNo);
            }
            else if("Payment cancelled by user.".equals(paymentCancel)) {
                Toast.makeText(FinalFormActivity.this, "Payment cancelled by user.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("UPI", "Cancelled by user: "+approvalRefNo);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(FinalFormActivity.this, "Transaction failed.Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("UPI", "failed payment: "+approvalRefNo);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("UPI", "Internet issue: ");
            Toast.makeText(FinalFormActivity.this, "Internet connection is not available. Please check and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public static boolean isConnectionAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()
                    && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                    && netInfo.isAvailable()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```